# Variables not showing after post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In *rails 4* a page is not showing an instance variable.
I have a form that triggers a post gives a flash message and redirects.
But the values are there and it never shows, any ideas?

**slim Form**

```
  - unless @flash == nil
    = @flash
  = form_tag '/contact' do
    = email_field_tag('email', nil, id:"email")
    input.btn-submit name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"
```

**Controller**

```
  def form_posts_here
    if UserMailer.zemail(params[:email]).deliver
      flash[:success] = "Thank you!"
    end
    redirect_to contact_path
  end

  def new
    @flash = flash[:success]
  end
```

Comment: And yes I checked that @flash and flash[:success] both go to the page but it's not updated live. Could it be turbolinks?

Comment: Have you try logging the params[:email] to check if its nil or not?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you don't have a way to show the flash messages.

Create a partial `_flash.html.erb` in your layouts folder and add this block of codes.

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
   <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %> alert-dismissible" role="alert" id="flash">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <%= simple_format(message) %></div>
<% end %>
```

You can access this by adding `<%= render 'layouts/flash' %>` in your application.html.erb.

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
def new
  flash[:success] = "Message goes here"
end
```

view:

```
- if flash[:success].present?
  = flash[:success]
```

Comment: Didn't work. The variables get to the page they just never show.